# MySQL select AND on multiple rows and multiple fields

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, knex.js

I have a table:

```
+ --------------------------+---------------------------+--------------+--------+
|           ID              |       SKU_ID              |   DKEY       |  DVAL  |
+ --------------------------+---------------------------+--------------+--------+
| cjamtti7z00aivmv4ffc9ttuw | cjamtti7z00afvmv4ai5i0ffy | Part         | A2030  |
| cjamtti7z00ajvmv4gztx7hq8 | cjamtti7z00afvmv4ai5i0ffy | Description  | Single |
| cjamtti7z00akvmv4zvrvtazj | cjamtti7z00afvmv4ai5i0ffy | Length mm    | 50     |
| cjamtti7z00alvmv4jxnryckh | cjamtti7z00afvmv4ai5i0ffy | Line Dia. mm | 6 - 10 |
+ --------------------------+---------------------------+--------------+--------+
```

I want to create a query that searches for SKUs that match a provided object:

`{ 
  'Fixing Hole Depth(mm)': '13 Min - 18 Max',
  'Inside Dia. (mm)' : '11',
  'Weight (g)' : '3'
}`

I can't seem to find a way to combine AND and OR clauses that gives me the desired result.

To summarise, I need the SKU_IDs that match ALL the criteria in the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In basic SQL it can be achieved with GROUP BY + COUNT.

```
SELECT SKU_ID
FROM your_table
WHERE (DKEY = 'Fixing Hole Depth(mm)' AND DVAL = '13 Min - 18 Max,') OR
    (DKEY = 'Inside Dia. (mm)' AND DVAL = '11,') OR
    (DKEY = 'Weight (g)' AND DVAL = '3')
GROUP BY SKU_ID
HAVING count(*) = 3
```

It's required to have each SKU_ID + DKEY to be unique(otherwise you may have 3 values for DKEY = 'Weight(g)' for the same SKU_ID and query will not work as expected)

Maybe there is some less verbose way but it should be RDBMS-dependant

Comment: Thanks so much! The 'HAVING count...' was where I was going wrong. I couldn't get rid the results that matched less than all criteria. I understand about the unique sku_id+dkey, and that is the case.

Comment: btw from practical standpoint this approach is buggy. I'd rather advice switching to document-oriented DBMS or use some external indexer.

Answer (score 0):

Your *where* clause can combine AND and OR easily, if you nest them correctly in brackets (). Try that.

Comment: Thanks. No matter how I nested or combined the clauses I couldn't get a correct match. @skyboyer's answer solved my problem by using "HAVING count..."